# VBA and Cases, assigning value based off of value in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have grades for students and levels of proficiency.

for example, for 5th grade, there are four levels of proficiency. The four levels of proficiency correspond to letters of the alphabet, so if a 5th grader got a letter assignment of B, then his proficiency level would be "Below Proficient" since for any letter in A to R would get a level of "Below Proficient" I was wondering how to do this with cases,

My rough idea of code was the following:

```
Function ConvertScores(Grade, Letter_Score)
Select Case ConvertScore(5, like "[A-R]")
    Case ConvertScore(5, like" 
        ConvertScores = "F & P Remedial"
    Case 2
        ConvertScores = "F & P Below Proficient"
    Case 3
        ConvertScores = "F & P Proficient"
    Case 4
        ConvertScores = "F & P Advanced"



End Function
```

So yea, I wish VBA had a list object, what is the list object in VBA?

EDIT: I was able to do it with multiple If statements, but it seems to me that cases would have been a better way to go.

Here is my code that I want to use with cases instead of multiple if-thens

```
Function ConvertScoresMOY(Grade, Letter_Score) As String
If Grade = "5" And Letter_Score Like "[A-R]" Then
    ConvertScoresMOY = "F & P Remedial"
ElseIf Grade = "5" And Letter_Score Like "[S-T]" Then
    ConvertScoresMOY = "F & P Below Proficient"
ElseIf Grade = "5" And Letter_Score Like "[U-V]" Then
    ConvertScoresMOY = "F & P Proficient"
ElseIf Grade = "5" And Letter_Score Like "[W-Z]" Then
    ConvertScoresMOY = "F & P Advanced"
Else:
End If
End Function
```

Comment: What is `ConvertScore`, it is not declared? Your description of what should be mapped to what is a bit puzzling to me... could you explain that again? And your code has flaws, you should take a minute to correct this...

Comment: Take a look at my latest edit.

Comment: To answer your sub question, the list objects you are looking for are called scripting dictionaries (enable the "Microsoft scripting runtime" reference.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets just start from insert all the conditions in one simple condition:

```
If Grade = "5" Then

End If
```

then you can use SWITCH CASE:

```
 Select Case Letter_Score
       Case Letter_Score Like "[A-R]"
             ConvertScoresMOY = "F & P Remedial"
       Case val Letter_Score Like "[S-T]"
             ConvertScoresMOY = "F & P Below Proficient"
 End Select
```

Comment: Thank you, but I"m not familiar with SWITCH, looking up how it works now. could you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

You could create your dictionary in another sheet, then use the VLOOKUP() function to search for a value on the first column and get the value on the second.